# Remove Malware from WordPress Database (from page & Posts)

Tags: wordpress, security, malware

How can I remove malware from WordPress Pages?

So far I updated all themes & plugins. Updated WordPress manually. Site scanned with Sucuri, MalCare, WPScan, WordFence.

now **I don't have any malware in PHP files**, I only have malware in Post & pages. (that mean only on the database)

How can I remove malware from Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to export your database and search, with a code editor, for common code utilized from hacker, for example:

- eval
- base64_decode
- shell_exec
- iframe
- gzinflate

or for example the error suppression

- error_reporting(0)

Comment: They have injected like this code

<script type="text/javascript" src="//XXXXX.com/apu.php?zoneid=2574011" async data-cfasync="false"></script>

Different number in every code.

Comment: If you have a huge post quantity I think that find&replace with regex is the most suited solution, you can do it in editor like sublime text in a database dump. Export db, replace, and reimport. If you need help with regex is better to open a question dedicated.  If the posts isn't a lot you can modify manually the dump by searching the common part of code "<script type="text/javascript" src=" pay attention to false positive

Comment: I have removed them with better search & replace plugin.

Comment: this one? https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Comment: Yes , this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got a recent clean copy of the database somewhere? If so you could use that as a comparison against the infected DB

How many pages does the site have? If there only a handful, just go through them one-by-one. Also delete and post revisions after cleaning posts.

Comment: All Page & Posts (around 20 pages & 200 posts) We have old back up somewhere, but we did some big changes after that backup. Thanks for the hint of post revision , I'm searching something on that.